# How to create one .exe from two .exes?

Tags: windows

I am working on a project, and I have two separate `.exe` files I would like to run on a user's computer depending on what bit version their OS is (ie, 32 bit vs 64 bit). Are there any utilities/scripting tools I can use to put these two `.exe` files together into one `.exe`? I would like the final executable to be able to determine bit version, then run one of the two separate executables.

Comment: You can use a "launcher" application that is a 32-bit application.  This would determine if the operating system is 32-bit or 64-bit launch the new process then close itself.

Answer (score 5):

One technique used by Sysinternals is to use a 32bit executable that contains the 64bit executable as well. When launched it checks if the system is 64bit and if it is unpacks the 64bit executable to a location like `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp` and runs it. Otherwise it continues normally.

For example the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) executable Procexp.exe will unpack procexp64.exe and run it.